# PHP/SQL Query woes

Tags: php, sql

For some reason this query activates PHP's die I set for it. I just don't get it because it works fine in just SQL, and all the PHP variables are correct. Name is varchar(12), Message is Text, InRoom is SmallInt, Time is DateTime, and IP is text.

```
<?php
    require 'functions.php';

    $room = sanitize($_POST['room']);
    $name = sanitize($_POST['name']);
    $message = sanitize($_POST['message']);
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    //print_r($_POST);
    $query ='INSERT INTO fate_chat_messages(Name, Message, InRoom, Time, IP) VALUES("'.$name.'", "'.$message.'", '.$room.', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "'.$ip.'")';
    $sql_result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die("Can't create post");
?>
```

Comment: Make your title describe the question please. There is a _reason_ that you couldn't write "problems" there, and it's not because we enjoy reading people's creative synonyms.

Comment: show what is in your $db , is it a connection obj ?

Comment: It dies to Can't create post and I can't tell you what the problem is. If I knew it I could fix it myself

Comment: @CyanPrime: Why don't you retrieve the MySQL error text with `mysql_error()`? Never mind fixing it, you're not even debugging it yet.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit you don't have to be so rude. I didn't know about mysql_error(). Could you explain how to use it?

Comment: Instead of `or die("Can't create post")`, try `or die("Can't create post"."<br/>".mysql_error())` to see your error as well.  You probably wouldn't have even needed this thread if you were able to see the error from the start.

Comment: @CyanPrime: I have not been rude at all. Explaining how the PHP MySQL API works is out of the scope of this comment thread. The PHP manual is a great reference and has many examples.

Answer (score 3):

`Time` is the name of a function in MySQL, and as such your query has an ambiguity.

Delimit field names in backticks:

```
INSERT INTO `fate_chat_messages`
  (`Name`, `Message`, `InRoom`, `Time`, `IP`)
VALUES (
  "a", "b", "c", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), "d");
```

And add code into your program to *display the error message that MySQL gives you*.

Answer (score 0):

You're single quotes and double quotes appear to be messed up. You should be escaping your variables anyway, but your query string should look more like this:

```
"INSERT INTO fate_chat_messages(
    `Name`, 
    `Message`, 
    `InRoom`, 
    `Time`, 
    `IP`
) VALUES('"
    .mysql_real_escape_string($name) ."', '" 
    .mysql_real_escape_string($message) ."', " 
    .mysql_real_escape_string($room) ."',
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), '" 
    .mysql_real_escape_string($ip) ."'
)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about this guys. Using mysql_error() that James told me how to use I figured out that I had my IP field set to unique. Removing that fixed the program. Thank you All for your help.